# How can we report errors and missing model data to Stanford NLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

For example, the Stanford Core NLP dependency parsing does not recognize the open compound noun "hot dog" as in "He ate a hot dog for lunch."  This is parsed to mean that he ate a dog that was hot.

[Screen capture of enhanced dependencies for this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAMeQ.jpg)

The online documentation (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/contact.html) says to ask questions here, but this does not seem to me to be an appropriate forum for reporting individual ommissions or errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread for dependency parse errors on GitHub here:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/694